# Run a sub-routine once the countdown is over

Tags: vba, powerpoint

```
Dim time As Date
Dim count As Integer

time = Now()
count = 60

time = DateAdd("s", count, time)

Do Until time < Now
DoEvents

With ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes("T").TextFrame.TextRange
.Text = Format((time - Now()), "hh:mm:ss")
End With
Loop
```

How do I add a provision for a certain sub-routine called `SendDetails` to run once the countdown is over?

```
While time < Now
DoEvents
Wend
SendDetails
```

If I use the above code instead of

```
Do Until time < Now
DoEvents
```

The text in `Slides(2).Shapes("T")` doesn't get updated.

Comment: If the SendDetails sub is in the same module, it's usually enough to call it by name as you've posted. Try setting a breakpoint (click in the VBA left margin until a brown bar appears over a line of code) and stepping through (F8 key) your code. Floating your mouse over variable names will show their value. Then you can see what's preventing the final statements from running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`While` and `Until` are opposites. When you start the loop, `time` is bigger than `Now()`, but as time goes, `Now()` will catch up. If you read the code as a simple English sentence it will make more sense.
Think of `While` to be "as long as 'condition' is true". `Until` means "do this until 'condition' is true".

You can do the testing before entering the loop or just prior to exiting.

In your case

```
Do While time < Now()
Loop

Do
Loop Until time > Now()
```

are the two clearest options. Take note of the `<` and the `>` characters.

Answer (score 0):

To add the provision of running another sub-routine `SendDetails` just add an If-Statement within the loop:

```
Do Until time < Now
DoEvents

If time < Now() Then
SendDetails
End If

Loop
```